# R squared in gls regression

Tags: r, regression

I want to create a gls regression that includes the value R squared and observations where the values "log likelihood" etc. are. The p values should be below the coefficients in the table. Here is an example of a code:
`

```
# import the necessary packages
library(nlme)
library(dplyr)
library(stargazer)

# create a new subset that only includes observations with a value in the "Price.Book.Value" column
dotcom_subset_MBV <- dotcom_subset %>% filter(!is.na(Price.Book.Value))
financial_subset_MBV <- financial_subset %>% filter(!is.na(Price.Book.Value))
covid_subset_MBV <- covid_subset %>% filter(!is.na(Price.Book.Value))

# Hypothesis 2: Fit GLS models
dotcom_model_MBV <- gls(X1.Month.Equity.Premium ~ crisis*Price.Book.Value, data =     dotcom_subset_MBV, method = "ML")
financial_model_MBV <- gls(X1.Month.Equity.Premium ~ crisis*Price.Book.Value, data = financial_subset_MBV, method = "ML")
covid_model_MBV <- gls(X1.Month.Equity.Premium ~ crisis*Price.Book.Value, data = covid_subset_MBV, method = "ML")

library(stargazer)
stargazer(dotcom_model_MBV, financial_model_MBV, covid_model_MBV, type = "text",column.labels =    c("Dotcom","Financial","Covid"),report=('vc*p'))
```

The only problem with the code above is that it shows the Log Likelihood, Akaike Inf. Crit. and Bayesian Inf. Crit. instead of the R squared values. The rest would be okay.

I tried the following:

```
omit.stat = c("ll", "AIC", "BIC")
```

and it works. However, it still doesn't show me the R squared. Then I tried:

```
add.lines = list(c(paste0("R-squared = ", round(r2_dotcom, 2)
```

and it includes a line that is called "R Squared" but without any values.

Comment: You don't show us in the code where `r2_dotcom` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using the `mtcars` data:

```r
data(mtcars)
library(nlme)
library(stargazer)
#> 
#> Please cite as:
#>  Hlavac, Marek (2022). stargazer: Well-Formatted Regression and Summary Statistics Tables.
#>  R package version 5.2.3. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stargazer
m1 <- gls(qsec ~ cyl + wt, data=mtcars)
m2 <- gls(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data=mtcars)
r2 <- c(cor(fitted(m1), mtcars$qsec)^2, 
        cor(fitted(m2), mtcars$mpg)^2)
stargazer(m1, m2, 
          type="text", 
          omit.stat = c("ll", "AIC", "BIC"),
          add.lines = list(c("R-squared", sprintf("%.2f", r2))))
#> 
#> =========================================
#>                  Dependent variable:     
#>              ----------------------------
#>                   qsec           mpg     
#>                   (1)            (2)     
#> -----------------------------------------
#> cyl            -1.173***      -1.508***  
#>                 (0.197)        (0.415)   
#>                                          
#> wt              1.356***      -3.191***  
#>                 (0.360)        (0.757)   
#>                                          
#> Constant       20.743***      39.686***  
#>                 (0.815)        (1.715)   
#>                                          
#> -----------------------------------------
#> R-squared         0.56          0.83     
#> Observations       32            32      
#> =========================================
#> Note:         *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The `add.lines` option expects a list and each vector in the list will be appended to the table with a different element in each column.  So you would need the vector of values to be "R-squared" and then each of the r-squared values printed in a string (that's what `sprintf()` does).

Also, note, that I've calculated the r-squared as the squared correlation between the observed and fitted values, but make no claim that this is statistically sound (though it is one way of calculating R-squared in the OLS model).